# Regex Logic - replace commas between two numbers with dots

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Hello there can i have an hint about how should i write the regex code to search for the commas (,) in those values between the |'...'| pattern? i need to find the commas and replace with dots(.) , if there's a comma in there of course.

```
|'2,3'|;|'5,6'|;|'2,1'|;|'3'|;|'6,5'|;|'9'|;|'7'|;|'4,4'|;|'4'|;|'1,1'|
```

expected result:

```
|'2.3'|;|'5.6'|;|'2.1'|;|'3'|;|'6.5'|;|'9'|;|'7'|;|'4.4'|;|'4'|;|'1,1'|
```

the pattern can be also what i will write below depending on some input parameters that i am going to receive in my method:

```
|'2,3'|,|'5,6'|,|'2,1'|,|'3'|,|'6,5'|,|'9'|,|'7'|,|'4,4'|,|'4'|,|'1,1'|
```

expected result:

```
|'2.3'|,|'5.6'|,|'2.1'|,|'3'|,|'6.5'|,|'9'|,|'7'|,|'4.4'|,|'4'|,|'1.1'|
```

this why i need a pattern for this because i don't know if i will receive the string with (;) or (,) separating the values

thanks so much

Comment: i updated my post, the thing is that i can receive this string with (;) or (,) separating the records depending on an input parameter that i am receiving in my method

Comment: Ok, so what code/pattern have you got so far? We need more details to be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regex Pattern

Here is the pattern that you can use to search for the commas `,` between two numbers

```
(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kAs4J/1)**

Comment: thank you so much for your answear, but it's not the expected result. i updated the post with the expected result

Comment: @JohnnyJoe Ok. I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: worked like a charm!!! thank you so much that's exactly how it is!, i upvoted you hope it counts

Comment: @JohnnyJoe Thank you for the upvote, too! You could also mark this question as the answer by clicking the tick below the upvote button!